# Console application using java collection framework and OOPS

Tags: java

I want to write a Console application using java collection framework and OOPS using eclipse IDE. Please guide me how should i begin and with some sample codes that might be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: try google search "hello world java eclipse"

Comment: http://www.javavirtues.com/2013/01/first-java-standalone-application-on.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Java Application in Eclipse.

Then at the static main() Method of your Class:

```
//To add objects in a Collection, in this case Strings
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("Michael");
strings.add("Jennifer");

//To show these objects in the Console
foreach(String string : strings){
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

This will create List containing String objects and afterwars print these on the Console. Your Collection could contain any type of Object, you are not limited to String only, e.g. `ArrayList<SomeClass>` or `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: thanks for the replies guys..What Im trying to do is get input from console store in any collection and perform some basic operations on the data(like deletion, insertion,sorting etc) guide me on this. Which collections to use when frequent updates are considered..